# Structural type

Tags: scala

I have found for self is very interesting a fact. For example i've wrote:

```
type A = { val st: Set[Any]
           val start: Set[Any]
           val Sigma : Set[Char]
           def tr(f: (Tuple2[Any, Any])=>Boolean): Set[Any]
             }
class Fon {
          val st: Set[Any]
          val start: Set[Any]
          val Sigma : Set[Char]
          def tr(f: (Tuple2[Any, Any])=>Boolean): Set[Any] = Set(out)
          def out: String = "is just example"
}
val a: A = new Fon
a.tr(f(Tuple2('a',0)))
```

But if i will try do call a.out - i get an error, that the type A have not exist 'out'
What happening to  this, how this to work?
Thanks.

Comment: This code is incorrect. At the very least, `Set[out]` and `Tuple['a',0]` are incorrect, because `[]` is being used instead of `()`. Also, this does not have anything to do with structural types -- if you do `val a: AnyRef = new Fon; a.out` it will complain all the same.

Comment: Maybe i don't understand something but can you do following:       `type A = { def out: String }; class AA { def out: String = out2;  def out2 = "out2"; val a: A = new AA; a.out` - result `String = out2`

Comment: @lisasha There's a `}` missing in your example. I assume after `out2`'s definition. Anyway, is that a question or a statement? If a question, then yes. If a statement, then I do not understand the point you are trying to make. Did you expect it to fail? If so, why?

Comment: Yes, here is missing `}` after out2 and it's was a question. Now me is more clear how it working. Anyway, why You said that it does not have to do with structural type? Thanks.

Comment: @lisasha Because it doesn't. As I said, if you replace `val a: A = new AA` with `val a: AnyRef = new AA`, it will give you the same error.

Comment: Not, not same. If i replace that how you talk - then at attempt do call method 'out' i get the message of error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such method as `A.out`, because of how you've defined the `A` type.  Thus, when you try to call a method called `out` on an object of type `A`, the compiler correctly tells you that no such method exists.

This is not related to structural typing, by the way - if you had made `A` a trait and had `Fon` extend it, you'd run into exactly the same problems.  Moreover, this is just how static typing systems work - the compiler can't guarantee that your code is typesafe so it won't compile it.

If you want to call the `out` method, then you'll need to refer to that object via a `Fon` variable:

```
val a: Fon = new Fon
println(a.out) // works fine, since a is guaranteed to be a Fon and thus have the method
```

Comment: All humor in fact that we can have is formally defined type and class or singleton, in general - object which will be represent it the to implementation. May be it's and not very good... Me wonder how and why the compiler allow this - use method 'out' in the method tr and infer that class Fon it's the type A.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it allows you to use one object ( `Fon` )  as it was another  ( `A` )  granted they have the same features.

Since `out`  is not a feature of `A` the compiler doesn't let you proceed.

Answer (score 0):

type A is an abstract class or trait. Its member variables and methods are abstract.

```
type A = {val st: Set[Any]
    val start: Set[Any]
    val Sigma: Set[Char]
    def tr(f: (Tuple2[Any, Any]) => Boolean): Set[Any]
  }
```

Fon is a concrete class, just implement type A all abstract member.

```
class Fon {
    val st: Set[Any] = null
    val start: Set[Any] = null
    val Sigma: Set[Char] = null

    def tr(f: (Tuple2[Any, Any]) => Boolean): Set[Any] = Set(out)

    def out: String = "is just example"
  }
```

So, you can define a variable, type is A ,and concrete instance is Fon

```
val a: A = new Fon
  println(a.tr(_ => false)) // Set(is just example)
```

extra: 
    `f: (Tuple2[Any, Any]) => Boolean` is a abstract higher-order function as a parameter,
so, if you want to call method tr, the `a.tr(f(Tuple2('a',0)))` calling mode can not resolve symbol f.
`f: (Tuple2[Any, Any]) => Boolean`  just getting a parameter, and return boolean.
so `(_ => false)` is a concrete implement.